# Как вернуть строку из функции

Tags: c, указатели

```
char *foo()
{
    char str[10];

    gets_s(str);

    return str;
}
```

Не могу понять почему не работает. В консоль выводит непонятные символы вместо введенной строки.

Answer (score 2):

потому что `char str[10]` - это локальная переменная и существует только внутри функции, когда вы выходите из функции, то переменная перестаёт существовать (ну если совсем просто)

чтобы иметь возможность возвращать из функции указатель на какие-то строки их надо создавать динамически:

в с++:

```
char* str = new char[10];
```

в c:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
```

или

```
char* str = (char*)calloc(10, sizeof(char));
```

> Ну можно еще создать переменную со статическим классом хранения. – @eanmos

```
char *foo()
{
    static char str[10];

    gets_s(str);

    return str;
}
```

> И ещё буфер можно передать как параметр для заполнения. – @Stanislav Volodarskiy

```
char *foo(char* str)
{
    gets_s(str);

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Ну можно еще создать переменную со статическим классом хранения. Добавьте для полноты, если не сложно.

Comment: И ещё буфер можно передать как параметр для заполнения.

Comment: [strdup()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)